# monodevelop -- using statements invalid

Tags: c#, monodevelop

http://grab.by/Hknm

[image]

The using package ZeldaEngine.Math; does not autocomplete, or even register as valid when entered manually. What gives?

-T

Comment: **Please** always post your code as *text* on Stackoverflow. Offsite screenshots (especially for showing your code) are not particularly welcome here.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your code.  Instead of a `;` you have a trailing `.`.

Change this line

```
using ZeldaEngine.
```

...to:

```
using ZeldaEngine;
```

Comment: @TristanPatrickRichter That's a new question.  And please don't reply using just hyperlinks